# Como alterar tamanho da WebView

Tags: android

Tenho aqui uma `WebView` que tem altura (*height*) de `0dp` definida no XML da atividade.

Como eu posso alterar a altura para `300dp` programaticamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após pesquisar um pouco descobri a solução para o meu problema

```
mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(350,350));
```

Há outra maneira que é por um `RelativeLayout` a volta da `WebView` e depois colocar no java :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) someLayout.getLayoutParams(); 
params.height = 130; 
someLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```